# Getting json data with nomitatim, although ok with mapbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, mapbox, nominatim

I'm using reverse geocoding mapbox webservice to get addresses from lat/long coords.

Getting it through mapbox (`http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/mykey/geocode/{mylong},{mylat}.json`) works fine using ajax'callback function to get json data.

Using the same method for openstreetmaps nominatim (`http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat={mylat}&lon={mylong}`), although I can access this URL, using the same methodology (ajax+callback+json) returns me always an JavaScript error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Why the json data is passed fine in mapbox but not in nominatim? It can't be the Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter in Apache header, I believe. If mapbox works fine, nominatim should also work.

Why I'm bothering with nominatim it's because it has more referenced coords.

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance,

Miguel

Answer (score 1):

> If mapbox works fine, nominatim should also work.

I'm not sure where this assumption is coming from: Mapbox uses an entirely different geocoder (carmen) than nominatim, as well as a different server, CDN, and everything else. What you're seeing is that Nominatim doesn't support CORS, and Mapbox does. You'll need to use JSONP if you want to use Nominatim for this.

Comment: Yes, i know. But i've already used the JSONP technique, like it is recommended in nominatim, and the server always returns 403 forbidden

Answer (score 0):

For MapBox:

The response header from MapBox is
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

while the nominatim.openstreetmap.org probably won't do this, so you will see
"Origin 'localhost' is therefore not allowed access"